# Ussd Post Request Keeps Giving Me Array To String Conversions Errors in postman

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'ussd'], function () {
        Route::post('/index', 'UssdController@index');
    });
```

Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

I need to read the incoming post request and then store the session id against the msisdn
        $input = $request->all();

//         Read incoming data
        $ussd_id = $request->input('USERID');
        $msisdn = $request->input('MSISDN');
        $user_data = $request->input('USERDATA');
        $msgtype = $request->input('USERDATA');
        $id = Session::setId($msisdn);


        // Start session for the incoming request
        Session::start();
    }
```

I have tried all i can think off but to no avail. I am new to Laravel and USSD as well

Comment: Welcome to SO ... is there a reason you need to set the session id yourself?

Comment: I think so. The documentation says: 

set your custom session id and start session for the incoming request.  

Note!! 

The only unique parameter is the msisdn.   

Set session id with the msisdn in order to track the session  

/  


session_id(md5($data['MSISDN']));
session_start();

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace in your error log from that error `array to string conversion`? I need to know file and line it happened on